# Gaining authorization to modify Spotify playlists using spotipy for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, authorization, spotify, spotipy

I'm currently attempting to use spotipy, a python3 module, to access and edit my personal Spotify premium account.  I've followed the tutorial on https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/docs/index.rst using the util.prompt_for_user_token method by entering the necessary parameters directly (username, client ID, secret ID, scope and redirect uri).  Everything seems to be fine up to this part. My code (fillers for username, client id and client secret for security reasons) :
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6oAe.png)

It opens up my default web browser and redirects me to my redirect url with the code in it.  At this point, I copy and paste the redirect url (as prompted) and hit enter.  It returns the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tMQE.png)

My redirect uri is 'http://google.com/' for this specific example. However, I've tried multiple redirect uris but they all seem to produce the same error for me. (and yes, I did set my redirect uri as whitespace for my application). I've spent hours trying to fix this issue by looking at online tutorials, trying different redirect urls, changing my code but have yet to make any progress.  I'm hoping I am just overlooking a simple mistake here!  Any feedback on how to fix this is much appreciated!

If it matters: I'm using the IDE PyCharm.

Comment: Hard to tell what might be the issue with it, some troubleshooting points are - checking everything looks as you'd expect in the URL of the OAuth approval page Spotify presents to you, that your client_id and secret match those of your developer account, same scopes, removing .cache-<username> and retrying?

Comment: @RachSharp first off, thanks for getting back to me on this issue! However I’m still having issues.  I tried redoing basically the entire thing and came across a similar issue.  Everything works as expected but ONLY when I set the scope as user-library-read.  If I attempt to use any other scope, I get the same ‘Bad request’ error as before. Any insight on this?

Comment: It's hard to say, check correct scope names, correct way of specifying multiple scopes maybe? If you attach a more complete example (e.g. add a complete minimal example, as code) to the post I can try and replicate.

Comment: @RachSharp heres my current code: 'import os
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

#credentials
user = 'ccmatt19'
desired_scope = 'playlist-modify-private'
id = os.environ.get('SPOT_CLIENT')
secret = os.environ.get('SPOT_SECRET')
uri = 'http://google.com/'

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username = user, scope = desired_scope, client_id = id, client_secret = secret, redirect_uri = uri)

Answer (score 1):

I had to use two different solutions to deal with the redirect_uri issue depending on which IDE I was using. For Jupyter Lab/Notebook, I could use a localhost for the redirect_url

`sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="your_client_id", client_secret="your_client_secret", redirect_uri="https://localhost:8890/callback/", scope="user-library-read"))`

For Google Colab, I had to use a publicly accessible website.  I think "https://google.com/" should work but I used my band's website so I'd remember that the redirect_uri had to match the one in your Spotify Develop dashboard settings.

`sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="your_client_id", client_secret="your_client_secret", redirect_uri="https://yourwebsite.com/", scope="user-library-read"))`

I just ended up using my bands website because it was easier for me to remember.  Make sure to go to the Spotify developer dashboard (https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications) and match the redirect_uri with what you are planning to use at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your redirect URL - working for me with:

```
import os
import spotipy.util as util

# credentials
user = 'username'
desired_scope = 'playlist-modify-private'
id = os.environ.get('SPOT_CLIENT')
secret = os.environ.get('SPOT_SECRET')
uri = 'https://localhost'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username=user,
                                   scope=desired_scope,
                                   client_id=id,
                                   client_secret=secret,
                                   redirect_uri=uri)
```

I think for your redirect url spotify requires the initial `http(s)` part - don't forget to add it to the white-list in your Spotify for Developers app too, as otherwise you will get 'invalid-redirect-uri'.

Comment: Ok I figured out the issue! Turns out that the redirect link didn’t have the ‘&’ symbol in it.  I added the ‘&’ at the end of the link and everything went smoothly.  Not sure why his was the case but I’m just happy I got it to work.  Thanks for the help I really appreciate it!