# Not sure how to fix "SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request" error

Tags: python-3.x, api, jupyter-notebook, spotipy

I'm trying to use a spotify api in jupyter notebook that will allow a user to type in the name an artist and it will return the pictures of the artist albums and the list of songs the artist has. I have been having a hard time trying to authenticate the token in the first place.

Below is my code I used to authenticate the token, but I can't seem to authenticate it:

```
 import sys

 import spotipy

 import spotipy.util as util

 token = util.prompt_for_user_token('jbbn','user-library-read','a2356bebcr8c46feb8add35e4ce56e8d','ea3ab1c177f7496a9536715727v7ca8e','http://localhost:8080')
```

(this is not my actual client id and secret)

Every time I run it, it redirects me to a blank page and tell me to copy and past the url in which I do and it returns "SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request"

Also, how do I make it so that I can input an artist's name and get back the cover of the album and album name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the symbol '&' after the URL when you paste it. I spent a while trying to figure it out and this [this post helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709664/gaining-authorization-to-modify-spotify-playlists-using-spotipy-for-python3?rq=1)