# I CAN NOT get an access token to use the Spotify API

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, spotipy

I am having a ridiculous time trying to get authenticated to use the Spotify API with oauth. Here is my code:

```
import os
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError


# Gives Spotify credentials:
username = "MY_USERNAME"
scope = "user-read-currently-playing"

# Gives developer app credential:
ID = "MY_ID_FROM_CREATED_SPOTIFY_APP"
SECRET = "MY_SECRET_FROM_CREATED_SPOTIFY_APP"
URI = "http://google.com/"

# Erase cache and prompt for user permission:
try:
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, ID, SECRET, URI)
except (AttributeError, JSONDecodeError):
    os.remove(".cache-" + username)
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, ID, SECRET, URI)

# Creates Spotify Object
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

I have watched multiple tutorials, read through countless other questions, and tried on multiple computers and code editors (I'm using PyCharm), and everytime I get `spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request`.
I really don't know what else to try here, and what is crazy to me is that I used this same code (with a different app ID) for a different project a few months ago.  I was able to successfully get authenticated following the same steps.  I'm clearly making one key mistake everywhere I try this though. I've restarted three times.  Some things I've tried: using a different redirect URI (I tried localhost and all the other recommendations), making sure I whitelisted the URI, making sure I have the backslash at the end of the redirect URI.  The only recommendation I haven't tried is "deleting the .spotify-token-cache file from my configure folder".  I'm on PyCharm on Windows, and can't for the life of me find this ".spotify-token-cache".  Any other possibilities? I just don't know why this wouldn't work now, after it did in the past.  Sorry if this is long-winded, I'm just at my wits' end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709664/gaining-authorization-to-modify-spotify-playlists-using-spotipy-for-python3?rq=1) question.  For some reason, I had to type & at the end of the link that you paste in.